# Pandas drop duplicates returning 'None' values and ''NoneType' object has no attribue 'function'' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a dataframe to an excel file, but I the dataframe has duplicate rows. When I try to remove the duplicate rows, I am getting an error"'NoneType' object has no attribue 'function''.

the code I am using:

```
colnames40 = rdf12.rename(columns = {"Time": "TimeH"})

result41 = pd.merge(colnames40, fdf31, how='inner', on=['Name', 'Date', 'High']).iloc[:,:-4].dropna(1).rename(columns = {"TimeH_x": "TimeH"})
result42 = result41.reindex(index=result41.index[::-1])
result43 = result42[['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'Check_2', 'High', 'TimeH']].reset_index()

readfile41 = pd.read_excel("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx")

readfile41['Count'] = np.arange(len(readfile41))
df41 = readfile41.set_index(['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'High'])
df42 = result43.set_index(['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'High'])

fdf41 = df42.combine_first(df41).reset_index().reindex(readfile41.columns, 
axis=1).sort_values('Count').drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

print("Updated TimeD1 Data Frame")
print(fdf41)

writefdf40 = fdf41.to_excel("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx", "Entries", index=False)
```

when I change `.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` to `.drop_duplicates(inplace=False)`, pandas does not remove the duplicate values.

Can someone help me fix this error and write the data?

Current output:

```
     Name  Location      Date Check_1  ... VWAP+1  $Volume+1  Trades+1  Count
2  Orange  New York  20200501       V  ...  5.580        NaN    6000.0    0.0
0   Apple     Minsk  20200505       V  ...  3.575        NaN     320.0    1.0
1   Apple     Minsk  20200505       V  ...  3.575        NaN     320.0    1.0
3   Steak    Dallas  20200506       V  ...  8.575        NaN     320.0    2.0
4   Steak    Dallas  20200506       V  ...  8.575        NaN     320.0    2.0
```

Desired output:

```
     Name  Location      Date Check_1  ... VWAP+1  $Volume+1  Trades+1  Count
2  Orange  New York  20200501       V  ...  5.580        NaN    6000.0    0.0
0   Apple     Minsk  20200505       V  ...  3.575        NaN     320.0    1.0
1   Steak    Dallas  20200506       V  ...  8.575        NaN     320.0    2.0
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicates#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates

Comment: return type is None, if `inplace=True` is given

Answer (score 0):

Either do this:

```
fdf41 = df42.combine_first(df41).reset_index().reindex(readfile41.columns, 
axis=1).sort_values('Count').drop_duplicates()
```

or

```
df42.combine_first(df41).reset_index().reindex(readfile41.columns, 
axis=1).sort_values('Count').drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately these do not work as the first one does not drop duplicates at all, and the second one still returns a non-value